# Android Activity.startActivity() and Dialog.show() order

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I need to show a EULA like dialog when a user starts up my app, but my app also has a splash screen of sorts that needs to be displayed before the dialog. I coded this up like so:

```
Activity A.onCreate(...) {
...
1. startActivity(Activity B) [this activity calls .finish() after x seconds]
2. dialog.show()
...
}
```

Logically, it seems like this should work. However, after I return to activity A from activity B, the entire screen is dimmed as if the dialog is showing, but without the dialog window.

I was able to work around this by reversing the calls as such and the dialog shows after activity B is done and no weird issues occur:

```
Activity A.onCreate(...) {
...
1. dialog.show()
2. startActivity(Activity B) [this activity calls .finish() after x seconds]
...
}
```

Anyone know why the order of calls is so important? To me they should work the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those functions are asynchronous functions.  This means that the code execution does not pause on them, but continues on to call the next lines.

Instead of calling them one right after the other, you need to wait for the one to return before calling the next.  If you want to show the Dialog first, add an [onDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) to listen for when the dialog is closed.  Within that listener you can start the next activity.

Comment: For the other way around, you could have activity B called with startActivityForResult(), and call .show() in your onActivityResult() method.

Comment: I would rather it be activity first and dialog second--is there anyway to do this and not use onActivityResult?

Comment: Why don't you want to use onActivityResult?  That is the correct way to do something after an activity finishes.  It seems, though, that you could show the eula over the splash screen, so you could start the dialog from activity B, and wait for them to hit ok, and then hide the splash screen.